# Select item by css

Tags: css

Is there any way to select the second child what has active class by css? When active class will be changed continuously.

```
<div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3b5px5dj/

Comment: @Hackerman That'll fail if there are more than three elements with the active class https://jsfiddle.net/1emeqktt/

Answer (score 0):

no, I don't think that is possible with CSS. but it's possible with JS,

```
let owlItem = document.querySelectorAll(".owl-item.active");
let SecondActive_owlItem = owlItem[1]; // 1 is second item in array
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally understanding the question, but here are some ideas.

## CSS

Try reading about CSS selectors. There are many ways, using CSS selectors, to select a specific element. Your case would probably involve an nth-child selector.

References:
[CSS Selectors - SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-selectors/)
[CSS Selectors Reference - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

## JQuery

If you know some JQuery, you could try the following:
First, give an ID to your parent  (let's say `test`)

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div> <!-- From what I understand, this is the target -->
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div> 
</div>
```

Now, you can select the target using the following JQuery script. For this one, I'm putting it in the `$('document').ready()` event, but you can put this in any other event.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  var actives = $('#test').children('.active'); // This returns an array of all the '#test' children that have the '.active' class 
  if(actives[1]) {// We check that there is a second children 
    // Do stuff, for example:
    $(actives[1]).css('display', 'none'); // actives[1] is surrounded by $() because it is a DOM element
  }
});
```